# Advice for implementing single sign-on?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, customization, openid, single-sign-on

Our organization is using Google Apps (standard edition) and we've just implemented a WP site.

I'd love any input on anyone who's used implemented Google Apps (in the last month or so) as the service for OpenID.

I tried the Janrain plug-in but am a little lost on what needs to be done outside of WordPress?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but I did try the JanRain Engage plugin recently. You need to have a JanRain account, and then an account with whatever services you want to enable so that you can authenticate against them -- e.g., Facebook, Twitter.

Comment: Oh, also, this might help: http://www.janrain.com/blogs/tutorial-janrain-engage-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 2):

**In Wordpress Admin**

1. Enable the JanRain Engage plugin
2. Go to Settings > Janrain Engage and enter your Engage API Key (which you can find on your Janrain dashboard under API Key).
3. Turn on self-registration.

**On the Janrain Dashboard**

1. Add your Wordpress domain under the Your Domains section.
2. Go to Sign-in and select the Choose Providers section. Pick the providers you want to support.

Go to your wordpress blog and it should allow you to pick one of your configured providers for logging in and for registering.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting article on the PHP, non-WP side of implementing SOS is here: http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/php/single-sign-on-with-openid-and-google-part-1/

Might be a good start at a custom plugin.